# How do I find this angle in the given quadrilateral?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

I'm not looking for the answer, but for how to work it out (IE what steps should I take; I think I've sketched the shape with the wrong measurements in each area) cuz I'm completely clueless. Here's the question:

'In a quadrilateral ABCD, AB = 4, BC = 5, CD = 7, DA = 5, and angle ABC is 87 degrees. Find angle ADC'

Thanks :)

Comment: It's going to involve a lot of trig, and a lot of numerical answers. The first step is to find out the length of $BD$.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel why do I need BD?

Comment: You can split the quad into two triangles ABC and CDA. You know all four sides; once you get BD you can solve for everything.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Use the [Law of Cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) in the triangle $\triangle ACB$ (to find $|AC|^2$) and in the triangle $\triangle ACD$ (to find angle the $\angle ADC$):
$$|AB|^2+|BC|^2-2|AB||AC|\cos(87^\circ)=|AC|^2=|AD|^2+|DC|^2-2|AD||DC|\cos(\angle ADC).$$